# How to get current Network name in Metamask api?

Tags: metamask

I wanna to check current rpc network is using Flashbot or Infura.

I know can using `window.ethereum.networkVersion` to get `ChainID` to check it is Mainnet or Goerli.

But I do not know how to check current rpc network is using Flashbot or Infura.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure nor can check now but you can have the url of the rpc in some `window.ethereum`properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
provider.getNetwork()
```

It will return the following (as example):

```
{
    "name": "bnb",
    "chainId": 56,
    "ensAddress": null,
    "_defaultProvider": null
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried `web3.currentProvider.getNetwork()` but not work, it return me: `web3.currentProvider.getNetwork is not a function`